# Is there a way to load only ID of entity/entities avoiding FetchGroup strategy ?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

There some cases when loading of only ID of an entity or IDs of a collection of entities (in a relationship, for example) is needed. For example I have en entity **Parent** and a collection of **children** in it

```
class Parent { 
    private List<Child> children; 
}
```

So, when I want to load **children** I want only the ids to be loaded for some cases, not whole state of children. I made a research and I found a way via Named FetchGroup, which means if I want to implement this I have to add for each Entity annotation @FetchGroup(name="id", attributes = {@FetchAttribute(name = "id")}). That work for the cases when I want to apply it for only an entity of course. For **children** case also **LoadGroup** should be configured.

The question here is: is there another strategy specially for loading of ONLY ID's, when an entity or entities are requested ? Or a way to indicate that ? Here I want to avoid annotation with @FetchGroup all entities I would like to applied that, just for loading of only ID. Of course, creation of a query like "SELECT ID FROM Parent WHERE ..." or "SELECT child.id FROM Parent INNER JOIN Parent.children WHERE ..." is also not a solution here since always should be defined, for all relationships and entities.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want one entity, you can use getReference() on EntityManager.

If it is a query, or relationship, then fetch groups in EclipseLink is your only option.